# Function overwrites student info only on the first student

Tags: c, struct

when i try to enter the student details as requested it takes the second course details and copies them into the first one. that only happens on the first student input. after the first student course infos are taken it works completely fine

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 22
#define MAX_COURSES 10
#define FIRST_NAME 11
#define LAST_NAME 11
#define Student_Amount 3
#define ALLSTUDENTSTRING 69
typedef struct Course_info
{
    int courseNum;
    int grade;
} COURSE_INFO;

typedef struct Student
{
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    int identity;
    int nofCourses;
    COURSE_INFO course_info[MAX_COURSES];
} STUDENT;

struct Course_info getCourseInfo(COURSE_INFO course_info)
{
    printf("Please enter your course number and grade: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &course_info.courseNum, &course_info.grade);
    
    return course_info;
}
struct Student getStudentInfo()
{
    struct Student student;
    int stringCounter = 0;
    char FirstName[FIRST_NAME];
    char LastName[LAST_NAME];
    printf("Enter student first name and last name(seperated by spaces) :");
    scanf(" %s", FirstName);
    strcpy(student.name, FirstName);
    scanf(" %s", &LastName);
    strcat(student.name, " ");
    strcat(student.name, LastName);

    
    printf("Please enter the student's ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &student.identity);

    printf("Enter number of courses taken: ");
    scanf("%d", &student.nofCourses);
    for (int i = 0; i < student.nofCourses; i++)
    {
        student.course_info[i] = getCourseInfo(student.course_info[i]);
    }
    return student;
}


void sortCourses(COURSE_INFO data[], int size)
{
    int i, j,temp;
    for ( i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (data[j].courseNum > data[j+1].courseNum)
            {
                temp = data[j+1].courseNum;
                data[j].courseNum=data[j + 1].courseNum;
                data[j + 1].courseNum = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int getStudentNames(STUDENT stuData[], int size, int courseNum, char stuNames[])
{
    int studentCount = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < stuData[i].nofCourses; j++)
        {
            if (courseNum == stuData[i].course_info[j].courseNum)
            {
                strcat(stuNames, stuData[i].name);
                strcat(stuNames, " ");
                studentCount++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s", stuNames);
    while (!strcmp(stuNames[i],"\0"))
    {
        if (i%2==0)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("%c", stuNames[i]);
        if (strcmp(stuNames[i]," "))
        {
            i++;
        }
        
    }

    return studentCount;

}
```

lets say i enter a course number and a grade, when i enter the second course info for the first student my first course info turns into both the first and the second

```
void main()
{
    int courseNum;
    char StuNames[ALLSTUDENTSTRING]="";
    printf("Welcome students!! \n");
    printf("and bye bye Pizzera \n");
    struct Student student_data[Student_Amount];
    for (int i = 0; i < Student_Amount; i++)
    {
        student_data[i] = getStudentInfo();
        
    }
     scanf("%d", &courseNum);
     printf("Names of students in course #%d", courseNum);
     getStudentNames(student_data,Student_Amount,courseNum,StuNames);
}
```

these are the inputs i run into the the problem with:

**Input**

```
Lois Noir
13345
2
1334 89
1252 92
Gur Lex
12587
2
1334 77
1445 81
Lois Lois
16577
1
1334 68
1334
```

instead of instead of the first students courseNum being 1334 and grade 92 i get that both of his courses are 1252 and grade 92.

Comment: Please a) fix the syntax error(s) in posted code and b) show the sample input that demonstrates the problem, detailing what *should* happen and what is happening instead.

Comment: `scanf(" %s", &FirstName);` Remove the `&`. Then enable compiler warnings and pay attention to them.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: @EricPostpischil i am trying to understand what you mean by that? segment my code block or just lower the amount of code overall in my post?

Comment: @idanyossifov Post code that we can copy/paste/compile and run, not only bits of your code. And show an example of input and expected vs actual output. Read all comments closely.

Comment: @Jabberwocky edited the question + inputs and expected output hope its understandable now. kinda new to stackoverflow

Comment: @idanyossifov are you sure the code you posted is actually the **exact same** code you're working with? The code you posted doesn't compile because there is no `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: @idanyossifov ... and there are lot's of warnings, all of which are actually errors. Unless you fix them, your code is wrong.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yeah this is copy paste from my visual studio. if its worth mentioning im using c library not c++ and other than that 1 issue i have its all working perfectly compilation wise. the programs runs and the string commands work for me without string.h library

Comment: @idanyossifov `strcmp(stuNames[i], "\0")` is wrong, you maybe want `stuNames[i] == 0)`. But anyway I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here...

Comment: @Jabberwocky my problem lies in the getStudentNames function where for some reason it wont put the first student into stuNames despite his course number being there.
first student has courseNum 1334 yet he isnt added to stuNames and when i debug it shows all of the first students courses are 1252 and 89 grade.
im thinking maybe my sortCourses function is faulty

Comment: A [mre] for this problem would be one sequence of code (not separate for `main` and the other routines) that other people can compile and run with no additions or changes. It should include `<string.h>`. It also includes sample output. You should modify the program to show output that demonstrates the problem, and you should state what output you expect instead. You write you get 1252 and 92, but we do not know how you know that since it is not shown in output. With certain problems, it is okay to show debugger output instead of program-printed output, but this problem is simple enough…

Comment: … that that is not necessary.

Comment: Never declare `main` as `void main()`. It should be `int main(void)`, `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, or something else supported by the implementation, or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code, that some are mentioned in the comments:

1. Missing `#include <string.h>`
2. `strcmp(stuNames[i], "\0")` is wrong, should be replaced with `(stuNames[i] == 0)`
3. `scanf(" %s", &LastName);`: `&` is extra
4. Your last function:

Instead of adding spaces, and then replacing them with newline, you can do:

```
strcat(stuNames, stuData[i].name);
strcat(stuNames, "\n");

// AFTER LOOP//
stuNames[strlen(stuNames - 1)] = 0;  // put terminating character to the end of string
```

### Extra

I would recommend to change this line:
`student.course_info[i] = getCourseInfo(student.course_info[i]);`
to
`getCourseInfo(&student.course_info[i]);`

where function will be:

```
void getCourseInfo(COURSE_INFO *course_info)
{
    printf("Please enter your course number and grade: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &course_info->courseNum, &course_info->grade);
}
```